# php number is stored as string?

Tags: php, wordpress, string, woocommerce, integer

I am working with wordpress / woocommerce and getting the price of a product like this:

```
$get_price = get_post_meta( $item_id, '_regular_price', true);
```

I am then calculating a discount and removing it like this:

```
$discount = 10;    
$minus = ($discount / 100) * $get_price;
$price = wc_price($get_price - $minus);
```

For some reason i get the following error:

```
CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in .....
```

Which points to the line that begins with $minus = ...

I have done some digging around using "gettype" and found that the woocommerce price is stored as a string, and not an integer.

I then changed the above to this to make sure it is now a integer:

```
$discount = 10;    
$minus = ($discount / 100) * (int)$get_price;
$price = wc_price($get_price - $minus);
```

This now works, but it rounds the price of the product down from £13.97 to £13.00. Any ideas why this could be? And any reason why the price is stored as a string in the first place?

**EDIT**

I have now tried the following:

```
$get_price = get_post_meta( $item_id, '_regular_price', true);
$new_price = (float) $get_price;
echo gettype($new_price);
```

Which still returns string.

Comment: Try `(float)` instead of `(int)`, but note that it's bad practice to use floating point arithmetic in monetary calculations -- convert them to integers by multiplying the values with `(10^(needed precision + 1))`, reversing that calculation for the final result.

Comment: You are casting the price to an int so it becomes 13: https://3v4l.org/54O3T - Handling prices as float values is kinda bad practice though because youll run into calculation issues everywhere.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec tried this and still returns as a string?

Comment: @danyo php-7.2 psysh session: `>>> gettype((float)'13.97');
=> "double`

Comment: @LoicTheAztec this is irrelevant, and $item_id = get_the_id(); which is the id of the current product.

Comment: Sorry but `$item_id` is used by Woocommerce orders items in general… I can't guess that $item_id is a product id… I always test everything and for me `$get_price = (float) get_post_meta( $product_id, '_regular_price', true);` gives a float number… Good luck!

Comment: what version of WooCommerce you are using?

Answer (score -2):

`$discount = '10';`  change this to

```
$discount = 10;
```

as `$discount = '10';`  is considered as string

you can use

```
 var_dump($discount);
```

to check the datatype

hope it helps :-)

Comment: i used gettype($discount) which results in a integer. That was just a typo by me. Discount is 10 and not '10'.

Comment: The OPs code shows clearly that the problem is `$get_price`, not `$discount`

Comment: @TomRegner  he has edited the question, please check the edit before down voting

Comment: @Ash-b The edit is irrelevant, the problem as stated was always the needed cast for `$get_price`, never `$discount`, the quotes there were a red herring for you.